# Spurious blank line with a declaration command of setspace as biblatex's bibsetup

Tags: biblatex, line-spacing, setspace

The following MCE shows that a declaration command of `setspace` as `biblatex`'s `\bibsetup` gives a spurious blank line at the beginning of the bibliography. Do you know why?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{knuth:ct:e}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
%
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\singlespacing}%
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless you want to clear out all of `\bibsetup`'s other settings, it may be better to do `\appto\bibsetup{...}` instead of `\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{...}`.

Comment: @moewe I also checked with `\appto` but I wanted to be sure anything else could interfere with the behavior I noticed. BTW, is there a way to check what are the `\bibsetup`'s other settings?

Comment: You can find the initial definition of `\bibsetup` in `biblatex.def`, but you can always say `\show\bibsetup` in your document and get the current definition sent to the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `\singlespacing` in `setspace.sty` is

```latex
% setspace.sty, line 345:
\newcommand{\singlespacing}{%
  \setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}%  normally 1
  \vskip \baselineskip  % Correction for coming into singlespace
}
```

which should be self-explanatory. In this case use

```
\setstretch{1}
```

instead of `\singlespacing`.

Comment: In your opinion, is this `\vskip \baselineskip` what one would expect? Isn't it just a workaround ("Correction for coming into `singlespace`")?